# Why is the "open" system call not featured in /usr/include/unistd.h ? (but "close" is)

Tags: posix, system-calls

In my comprehension the **open** and the **close** system call seem very much related.

- both deal with files
- available in most all unix flavours (?any unix that does not feature them existed?)

I therefore expected to find them declared *both* in the `/usr/include/unistd.h` header file. However -strangely- there is only "close", but no "open" declared there (on my 4.17 linux kernel system)?

The omission of the **open** system call in `unistd.h` seems confirmed reading the [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html)

which tells in paragraph "Declarations"

> The following shall be declared as functions and may also be defined
>   as macros. Function prototypes shall be provided.
>
> int          access(const char *, int);
>   unsigned     alarm(unsigned);
>   int          chdir(const char *);
>   int          chown(const char *,> uid_t, gid_t);
>   int          close(int);
>   [... some more declarations, but no "open"]

Then -stangely to me again - the file `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` contains the line

```
#define __NR_open 2
```

as if unistd.h still cared somewhat about "opening of files"?

Comment: I don’t know the answer to the POSIX question (apart from historical reasons; `open` is defined in [`fcntl.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html)), but I do know that `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h` isn’t related to `unistd.h`, it’s the fallback list of 64-bit syscall numbers on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background is that you need to

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

in order to get the `open()` related flags anyway, and there should be a chance not to pollute the name space more than needed.

If `open()` would be in `unistd.h`, this file would need to `#include` `fcntl.h` and this is not wanted as a default.

The file unistd_64.h is an inofficial vendor internal include file and what's inside this file is not subject of the POSIX stdandard.

Comment: In addition, POSIX allows `fcntl.h` to include `unistd.h` itself. But is there any rationale to all this beyond “that’s how it was, now we have to live with it”?

Comment: Not really, POSIX allows to make some symbols from `unistd.h` visible. This allows to include official and inofficial sub-include files like `sys/types,h` and `sys/unistd.h`.

Comment: “Inclusion of the <fcntl.h> header may also make visible all symbols from <sys/stat.h> and <unistd.h>.” Also, in what sense is [`sys/types.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) unofficial? But I was more interested in the second part of my comment.

Comment: sys/unistd.h is unofficial, files like that exist in order to make the POSIX rules easier to implement. This is needed since POSIX decided to make auto inclusion of all needed parts mandatory and there still was the wish to limit the visible symbols.

Comment: I never said anything about `sys/unistd.h`, but never mind.

Comment: Well, you asked for an unofficial include file and I pointed to the one in my list that is unofficial.

Comment: No, I misunderstood your comment and thought you were saying `sys/types.h` is unofficial, and asked “in what sense is `sys/types.h` unofficial?”. It’s all good, but I’d still like to know the rationale (if there is one beyond historical precedent).